# 405 Method Not Allowed after deployment on vercel (using react app)

Tags: web, vercel, supabase, http-status-code-405, redwoodjs

I have an app using redwood, supabase and prisma.

I've just deployed it on vercel and now I can't access to my data. I have an error 405 Method Not Allowed, but I don't understand why, as it works well on localhost.

I didn't forget to add env var, but I don't have vercel.json file as I don't know how to write it.

Here some image to add more context :

Actual :
[HomePage with bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnZB7.png)
[Console error 405](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYJxZ.png)

Expected :
[HomePage working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmO9e.png)

If you have any idea or if you want more information, please tell me.